# How should users be directed if they ask for a password reset, but their email is no longer valid?

Tags: user-expectation, login, email, notification, password-recovery

I manage a website where users can request a password reset via an automated email.

What experience should I provide to users who have requested a password reset, but whose registered email address is no longer valid?

Obviously, we have no way of getting ahold of those users through those invalid/incorrect email addresses, and the automated password reset emails are getting bounced back.

One idea I had was to include a note on the confirmation page that reads something along the lines of, "if you don't receive the password reset email, please use our contact form with your name and current email address," but I'm unsure whether this is a solid or the most helpful solution.

I appreciate any guidance this community can provide for this use case.

For reference, I've read the following related posts on this site:

- [Should (and how should I) I use email addresses for login without validating them?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/23432/should-and-how-should-i-i-use-email-addresses-for-login-without-validating-the)
- [How to handle "forgot password" when user has not confirmed email?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/30249/how-to-handle-forgot-password-when-user-has-not-confirmed-email)
- [What's the best way to handle password reset requests where the user hasn't registered with the entered email address](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/89116/whats-the-best-way-to-handle-password-reset-requests-where-the-user-hasnt-regi)

Comment: You might want to consider a more generic help message. e.g. "Still can't sign in? Contact us at <support@productname.com>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all if you want to be save in the future provide your users the possibility to enter additional information that could restore their account in such a case, like:

• Mobile number
• Second E-mail

This way you gave your users the chance to prevent this situation, even if many will not use it, they will have a hard time to blame you.

Regarding your phrasing question:
Don't just tell him to use the the contact form, provide him the contact form right there with a submit button after he clicked the "Forgot password" or "I dont have access to my e-mail anymore".